# Variable in cursor select statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was trying to fetch the count of multiple tables using PLSQL, having 4 tables - testing, test1, test2, test3.

Table testing having the details of all the tables whose count I need and was using the following program using cursor to achieve the same.

```
declare
var varchar2(20);
var2 varchar2(20);
cursor C1 is select tab_name from testing;
begin
open C1;
loop
fetch C1 into var;
exit when C1%notfound;
select count(*) into var2 from var;
dbms_output.put_line(var2);
end loop;
end;
/
```

But getting below error on executing:

```
select count(*) into var2 from var;
                               *
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 32:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`execute immediate`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/executeimmediate_statement.htm) with `dynamic sql`.

```
declare
    var varchar2(50);
    var2 number;
    cursor C1 is select tab_name from testing;
begin
    open C1;
    loop
        fetch C1 into var;
        exit when C1%notfound;
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || var into var2;
        dbms_output.put_line(var2);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

you can use `Implicit Cursors` like;

```
declare
    var number;
begin
    for i in (select tab_name from testing) loop
        execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || i.tab_name into var;
        dbms_output.put_line(var);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
var varchar2(20);
var2 varchar2(20);
cursor c is select field1 from testing;
begin
for c1 in c
loop
var2:=c1.field1;
execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || var2 into var;
-- below query won't work as we are creating a dynamic SQL statement
 --select count(*) into var from var2;
dbms_output.put_line(var);
end loop;
end;
```